# Can only see the traffic of the host in Wireshark?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I need to analyze the traffic of my network; the outgoing traffic that hosts in that LAN generate directed to a certain IP using HTTP protocol.

I've tested it with Wireshark, but I can only see the traffic of the host where is running at; the traffic generated by other hosts is not being captured.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Setting Wireshark to ["Promiscuous" mode](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) allows you to gather packets that aren't directed at your network end-point if you're on a Wifi connection.  Link shows how to set Wireshark to capture in Promiscuous mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if your hosts are connected via hub. If switch is used other host's frames will not reach wireshark host.

Comment: Is impossible to do this in a switched network?

Comment: In switched network the packets from other hosts (excluding broadcasts/multicasts) will not reach your network interface. If your router is able to run wireshark/tcpdump you cat run it there and you will capture almostall packets